# Chat code in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

hi i m Windows 8 Developer and i am new in this so any one can help me to how to make chat app with using WCF service? any codes or links please send to me

i have search a lot in Google but i cant found best code.

i have refer these two links

http://rudolfantonio.com/blog/real-time-windows-store-app-with-signalr-sample-code-c-chat-app/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78d182/signalr-sample-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Seems like you already have some great samples.

Comment: You are also asking for than can be answered in a single question's answer.

Comment: Don't use WCF Service since its not supported directly in Univversal Apps. What i meant is the Option to add WCF service as ServiceRefernece is removed in Universal Apps.